# If $A \implies B$ and $B \implies A$, does this imply that $A=B$?

Tags: logic

I have this problem, but I didn't find anything on the internet. $(A \implies B \implies A) \Leftrightarrow (A=B)$?

Comment: What does "=" mean in this context?

Comment: What does $A=B$ mean for propositions?

Comment: It implies that they are equivalent.

Comment: What have you tried, besides searching the internet?

Comment: Search for bi-conditional.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA if it implies that they are equivalent, then of course it's true! That is precisely the definition of "double implies" ($\iff$)!

Comment: If $A \implies B$ and $B \implies A$, then this is the definition of  $A\iff B$.  But equivalent is not usually thought to be the same as equality

Comment: @SayanDutta - are you saying that the comment sounds trivial? Yes it is :-) But so is the question ...